# Is there any other prototyping tool that can be used along with google polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I understand Google Polymer itself is a prototyping tool. But its not supporting all the sophisticated designs we need . Is there any other tool which can help me in incorporating the visual aspects of the design long side with google polymer.

Answer (score 0):

There is the polymer designer here: https://github.com/Polymer/designer. But from what I understand, it's still under heavy development.

Also, there is a simpler designer that you can use here: https://polymerlabs.github.io/wizzywid/

This was talked about in the Polymer summit. You can find the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=otcmcNY-3pk&t=1s